# SQL XML to Return All Element Values

Tags: sql, xml, element

This should be simple but cannot get it to work after trying multiple suggestions from things I researched. I have some basic XML and just want to return the values from all the elements in seperate rows in a query result.

```
<Root>
  <QueryRequest>
    <ReturnedReuslts>
      <Rows>
        <Row>"1","Value 1"</Row>
        <Row>"2","Value 2"</Row>
        <Row>"3","Value 3"</Row>
      </Rows>
    </ReturnedReuslts>
  </QueryRequest>
</Root>
```

I want it to return

```
Column 1  Column 2
--------  --------
1         Value 1
2         Value 2
3         Value 3
```

If I can't get it into two different columns, I'll settle for:

```
Column 1  
----------------
"1","Value 1"
"2","Value 2"
"3","Value 3"
```

Comment: what's the sql engine? version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server:

```
declare @strxml xml;
set @strxml = '<Root>
  <QueryRequest>
    <ReturnedReuslts>
      <Rows>
        <Row>"1","Value 1"</Row>
        <Row>"2","Value 2"</Row>
        <Row>"3","Value 3"</Row>
      </Rows>
    </ReturnedReuslts>
  </QueryRequest>
</Root>'

select 
    substring(t1.col1, 1, charindex(',', t1.col1) - 1) Column1, 
    substring(t1.col1, charindex(',', t1.col1) + 1, len(t1.col1)) Column2  
from 
    (select  
         col1 = replace(Node.Data.value('.', 'varchar(200)'), '"', '')
     from  
         @strxml.nodes('/Root/QueryRequest/ReturnedReuslts/Rows/Row') Node(Data)) t1
```